# EF CORE Power Tool for VS 2019 Fail

Tags: entity-framework

I download the EF CORE Power Tool extension today for my Visual Studio 2019 (. NET Core 2 2). It installed successfully. However, I kept getting System IO 'Path' Exception with "c:\projects\" when I tried to add the DB context diagram.

Am I missing something or not configuring it correctly?

Comment: Please post an issue with a full stack trace on the EF Core Power Tools GitHub repo

Comment: To replicate the issue:

1. Right-click on my project that has dbcontext file
2. Select "EF Core Power Tools" -> "Add DbContext Model Diagram"

I will post the stack trace on the next comment because it is too long.

Comment: System.NotSupportedException: The given path's format is not supported.
   
at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.EmulateFileIOPermissionChecks(String fullPath)
at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)

Comment: at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter.CreateFile(String path, Boolean append, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean append, Encoding encoding, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean checkHost)

Comment: at System.IO.File.InternalWriteAllText(String path, String contents, Encoding encoding, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.File.WriteAllText(String path, String contents, Encoding encoding)
   at EFCorePowerTools.Handlers.ModelAnalyzerHandler.GenerateDgml(String processResult, Project project) in C:\projects\efcorepowertools\src\GUI\EFCorePowerTools\Handlers\ModelAnalyzerHandler.cs:line 122

Comment: at EFCorePowerTools.Handlers.ModelAnalyzerHandler.Generate(String outputPath, Project project, GenerationType generationType) in C:\projects\efcorepowertools\src\GUI\EFCorePowerTools\Handlers\ModelAnalyzerHandler.cs:line 80

Comment: Could you please post an issue here, and provide more details about your project: https://github.com/ErikEJ/EFCorePowerTools/issues

Comment: Hi Erik,  my issue is that the Visual Studio 2019 will not run without throwing exception.  All I want to do is checking out the tool to see how it works.  I saw your video and I wanted to try it out on my project.

I am using .NET EF Core 2.2 to generate my database (code-first approach) and it would be nice to be able to see it graphically.  It is not a show stopper if I don't have this tool for my project.  My previous posts are the exception from the tool when I ran it.

Comment: Please just create an issue here https://github.com/ErikEJ/EFCorePowerTools/issues , and continue our discussion there, as I already stated.